# Weird output of method for circular import in Python

Tags: python, oop, dynamic, module, package

There are two modules in the same directory.

I'm using Python 3.2

One is `a.py` like this:

```
import b
class orig:
    def test(self):
        print("hello")


o = orig()
o.test()
```

Another is `b.py` like this:

```
from a import orig
orig.test=lambda self: print("wrong")
```

When I run command like this:

```
python a.py
```

I expect to see only one `hello` in the output, however, I see two `hello` in the output. Each `hello` in a seperate line.

Also, I'm confused that how python deal with situations that two modules imported by each other.

Does anyone have ideas about this?

Comment: Circular imports should be avoided in general

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you run a python script directly, like you are doing with `python a.py`, the python interpreter doesn't *guess* what that file's module path should have been; it just creates a module called `__main__` and runs it.

another subtlety is that each time python encounters an import, it *first* creates the module and stores it in `sys.modules` so that all other imports of the same module produce the same module object.  Only once it's left that breadcrumb does it start executing the python code that implements that module.

so here's what happens, step by step, you type `python a.py` at your shell console, python 
creates a `__main__` module and starts evaluating that file.

```
the file being parsed
  |
  |       the module being imported       
  |         |     
./a.py  __main__  1:  import b
```

ok, so the first thing that happens is that `a.py` imports something.  it has never been imported before, so it searches the path and finds `b.py`;  since we're still trying to import another file, i'll indent a bit to show that.

```
    ./b.py  b  1:  from a import orig
```

And the first thing that happens in `b.py` is that it tries to import `a`.  but `a` has never been imported either; when python searches the path, it finds `a.py`

```
        ./a.py  a  1:  import b
```

looks familiar; but b *has* been imported; this `b` will be the same one (which is still in the process of being imported!

```
        ./a.py  a  2:  class orig:
        ./a.py  a  3:      def test(self):
        ./a.py  a  4:          print("hello")
        ./a.py  a  5:  
        ./a.py  a  6:  
        ./a.py  a  7:  o = orig()
        ./a.py  a  8:  o.a()
```

ok.  a class is created, instantiated, and some output occurs;  `a` is now finished importing; that's good, because `b` used a from import,  that means that the `orig` needs to exist by now, or else the import would fail.

```
    ./b.py  b  2:  orig.test=lambda self: print("wrong")
```

`b` monkey patches `a.orig` (note; not `__main__.orig`).  `b` is finished importing now too.

```
./a.py  __main__  2:  class orig:
./a.py  __main__  3:      def test(self):
./a.py  __main__  4:          print("hello")
./a.py  __main__  5:  
./a.py  __main__  6:  
./a.py  __main__  7:  o = orig()
./a.py  __main__  8:  o.a()
```

now `__main__` is defining a class, instantiating it and printing some output.  Also note that this is a definition for the class `__main__.orig`, not the `a.orig` b modified.

Hope that clears up some confusion.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting two lines output because you are executing a.py twice: once as the main program, and once when it is imported into b.  Avoid circular imports, and definitely definitely do not import your main program.

Another side effect of importing the main program: you actually have two classes named `orig` in this program now.

Answer (score 0):

Just to second @TokenMacGuy and @Ned: If you replace the end of a.py with:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    o = orig()
    o.test()
```

you will get only one "hello".

And, indeed: avoid circular dependencies!